# (Angular) with many subscribers

Tags: javascript, angular, performance, typescript, rxjs

What happens when you have too many subscribers? I have a **directive** that watches every route events, and I placed my directive inside of a **NgFor**.

I am just new to RxJS and I'm very concerned about the performance.

Answer (score 1):

## Performance Notes:

1. **Event Loop:**
   All subscribing methods or functions are called as soon as an event fires, but not directly. They are handled by the Event Loop, and it can handle a lot of events firing at once.
2. **I/O bound vs CPU bound functions:**
   But if the functions being called are not I/O bound, i.e. simple input output stuff, like logging, or calling Google Analytics, then performance will dip.
   *Imagine running Path Finding algorithm (A*, Dijsktra) on each event fired!*
3. **Unsubscribe as a best practice:**
   Another thing to keep in mind is to unsubscribe the event, in NgOnDestroy(), of the directive, it'll keep the potentially growing amount of events from spiraling out of control!